# mysql join table on condition that compares two records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a left join with an on statement that has requirements in two records. Essentially, i am trying to determine if two users are members of a group via a **groupId** and **userId**

This is where I started

```
LEFT JOIN groups AS g1 ON g1.status = "active" AND g1.userId = "user1"
LEFT JOIN groups AS g2 ON g2.status = "active" AND g1.groupId = g2.groupId AND g2.userId = "user2"
```

The problem with the two the joins is that the first join is going to select the first available record that meets this condition. The second join will be generated from the first join due to the **groupId**. This may work if the groupId for the second is the same. However, this is not the case as users can be members of a bunch of different groups. Essentially, I am trying to create a join statements that attempts to find a similar group (via **groupId**) between the two users. If the group is not there is just returns null (reason for me using left join).

How can I create a join that compares a similar groupId between two records?

Thanks

Here is the entire query

```
SELECT u*, code.description AS statusText...., CASE WHEN u.id = "ME" THEN 1 ELSE g2.groupId END AS public
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN codes AS code ON code.code = u.status
LEFT JOIN groups AS g1 ON g1.status = "active" AND g1.userId = u.id
LEFT JOIN groups AS g2 ON g2.status = "active" AND g1.groupId = g2.groupId AND g2.userId = "ME"
WHERE u.id = :u
LIMIT 1
```

Where ME equals your user login and :u is the user we are looking up

Essentially, i am trying to compare if you and another user a part of the same group.

Results would look like an array with the following details

```
[userId] => 1
[date] => 2015-06-16 00:00:00
[player] => first name
[email] => email 
....
[public] => 1   <- this is the important variable i am trying to get. I want to return a number that i will treat as a boolean. The number tells me that i have a group in common with the user i am looking up
```

The group table

```
| userId | groupId | colum1 | ...  | 
+--------+---------+--------+------+
|    1   |    1    |    1   | ALL  | 
+--------+---------+--------+------+
|    1   |    5    |    1   | NONE | 
+--------+---------+--------+------+
|    6   |    1    |    1   | ALL  | 
+--------+---------+--------+------+
|    2   |    3    |    1   | NONE | 
+--------+---------+--------+------+
```

From this example of the table data you can see that users 1 and users 6 are part of the same group. If this was the only data in the table than my join statement would work. However, this is not the case and if user 1 and ME were both part of group 5 my statement would fail

I would prefer not to use a subquery

Comment: Maybe share the entire query?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I was just writing up an answers with a subquery.  That is simply the easiest way to do it.  You can probably come up with a fancy way to do it without a subquery, but there probably isn't a valid reason to avoid the subquery here.

Comment: @ers81239 I am willing to have a look - probably took longer to write your comment than the statement -thx

Comment: @iPoo, well, you say you realize you can do it that way, so no need for me to do it for you!

Comment: @ers81239 correct im just curious what your solution would be as oppose to mine

Comment: @ers81239 my subquery  =>  (SELECT r.groupId FROM groups AS r INNER JOIN groups AS rr ON rr.groupId AND rr.userId = "ME" WHERE r.userId= u.id LIMIT 1) END AS public